# How to restrict access to a small user community (IAM users) in GCP / Cloud DNS / HTTPS application

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-oauth, google-cloud-dns

I have a request to restrict the access (access control) to a small user community in GCP.
Let me explain the question.

This is the current set up:

- A valid GCP Organization: MyOrganization.com (under which the GCP project is deployed / provisioned)
- Cloud DNS (To configure domain names, A & TXT records, zones and subdomains to build the URL for the application).
- Oauth client set up (tokens, authorized redirects URIs, etc.).
- HTTPS load balancer (GKE -managed k8s service- with ingress service), SSL certificate and keys issued by a trusted CA.
- The application was built using python + Django framework.

I have already deployed the application (GCP resources) and it is working smooth.
The thing is that, since we are working in GCP, all IAM users who has a valid userID@MyOrgnization.com can access the application (https://URL-for-my-Appl.com).

Now, I have a new request, which consists in restricting access (access control) to the application only for a small user community within that GCP organization.

For example, I need to ensure that only specific IAM users can access the application (https://URL-for-my-Appl.com), such as:

1. user1@MyOrganization.com
2. user2@MyOrganization.com
3. user3@MyOrganization.com
4. user4@MyOrganization.com

How could I do that, taking into account the info I sent earlier ?

thanks!

Comment: please just to clarify, currently how do you already manage authentication restricted to @MyOrganization.com ? Do you mean home made development with OAuth ?

Comment: Thanks ThierryFalvo for replying it. The current set up is that any user authenticated with @MyOrganizartion (regular intranet users) can access the URL for the application. I have investigated a bit, and it seems that RBAC might be a solution to my original question. What do you think ? With regard to OAuth, we have some OAuth's credentials / token in place to set up it.

Comment: As Guillaume's answer, IAP is really a good choice to manage authentication  inside a domain easily and securely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud IAP (Identity Aware Proxy)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/) in order to do that.

> Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) lets you manage access to applications
>   running in App Engine standard environment, App Engine flexible
>   environment, Compute Engine, and GKE. IAP establishes a central
>   authorization layer for applications accessed by HTTPS, so you can
>   adopt an application-level access control model instead of using
>   network-level firewalls. When you turn on IAP, you must also use
>   signed headers or the App Engine standard environment Users API to
>   secure your app.

Note: you can configure it on your load balancer.

It's not clear in your question if your application uses google auth (but considering that you talk about org-restricted login I think so) - if that's the case you should be able to enable it without virtually touching anything in your application if you are using the Users API.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution is to [deploy IAP (Identity Aware Proxy) on your HTTPS Loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto)

Then, grant only the user that you want (or create a gsuite user group and grant it, it's often easier to manage)